# How to fetch data from more than one collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I have data from several collections, I'm try to fetch data from mongoDB using Go.
Here is the json I want to display:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"total": 59,
"subtotal": 10,
"values": [
    {
        "name": "Anita",
        "age": 24,
        "other": {
            "a": "abc",
            "b": "qwe"
        }
        "detail": [
            {
                "detail": "Detail a",
                "description": "Desc"
            },
            {
                "detail": "Detail b",
                "description": "Desc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Banji",
        "age": 23,
        "other": {
            "a": "abc",
            "b": "qwe"
        }
        "detail": [
            {
                "detail": "Detail a",
                "description": "Desc"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

How to make json data like above using go?

Comment: This might be an option: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ , or you can fetch data from each collection and then combine them with struct or map.

Comment: Maybe [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) would work